# PnP modern search: override default results with keyword results

Tags: sharepoint-search, pnp, modern

I have a modern search box and results web part on a page. If I add a wildcard to the default search query, all results display as expected. However, when a search term is entered, the results aren't filtered. On page load, I'd like to see all results from a default query (say, all docs in a library) and then filter those results based on a search term entered.

I've tried formatting the KQL default search syntax using a wildcard "*", but the results don't change when a search keyword is entered. Is there a KQL option to resolve this, or is it not possible?

Comment: What exactly your KQL is? Could you provide example?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out - the key is to include the {searchTerms} token in the query template, so something like:

```
Path: https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/Shared%20Documents {searchTerms}
```

That then overrides the wild card (or path) in the default search query when a search term is entered.